# Does anyone know how to get value of pickerview and send that value to another pickerview of viewcontroler

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uipickerview

Hi i have 3 picker views from one view controller.imagine view A.when i selected data from view A those data need be go to display other view controller of picker views.I don't know how to do that and i tried lot.please let me know someone know this answer. Thank you.

Comment: You need to compare the picker view from the picker view that comes in delegate method.

Comment: Hi.i just got the selected value and displayed to view b.but i want to get that selected name.

Comment: which data do you want to pass? whole arrray? or single selected row or multiple selected row? how do you want to pass data?

Comment: Well, you need to extract it from your datasource then.

Comment: hi Lion
not a whole array.i just need to get selected row.and i want it from swift language.im using prepareforsegue method to send data to view b.i can set that value into textfield.i want to get that value to pickerview in view b.

Answer (score 1):

gihanghost,

UIPickerView has number of delegates to inform its status.

One that you can make use of would be,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    //you can access the selected object using the row value 
    //you must have provided the array as a data source to your pickerView
   YourObject *obj = [YourPickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row]
}
```

This delegates gets called when user scrolls through pickerView options and each row comes to focus.

If you want to access the currently selected row in pickerView later in your code you can use the code below

```
 NSInteger row = [self.yourPickerViewInstance selectedRowInComponent:0];
 YourObject *obj = [YourPickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row]
```

Now you have the selected object with you. Pass it to whichever view controller you want :)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi Sandeep Bhandari. I need it from swift language.i tried to send trough prepareForSegue.i got the value of selected value to textfield.but i want to that selected name to pickerview.not a value.